# object is not callable. Error Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and this is a code I've recently received and its working until the 29th line. This is where the error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:/computing/11woojos_A453/A453_ASSIGNMENT/Task two/task 2 SO.py", line 30, in <module>
    print (keyword_encrypt)(shift_key, phrase)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from itertools import islice, cycle

phrase = input('message you would like to encrypt: ')
shift_key = input('shift key: ')

def keyword_encrypt(key, phrase): # e.g. "ba","abcde"
    # make phrase and key into arrays of letters (equal length)
    phrase = [ letter for letter in phrase.lower()]     # e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] 
    key = list(islice(cycle(key.lower()), len(phrase))) # e.g. ['b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
    encrypted = []

    for i in range(len(phrase)):
        k_letter = (ord(key[i]) - ord('a'))
        p_letter = (ord(phrase[i]) - ord('a'))

        new_letter =  p_letter + k_letter

        if new_letter >= 26:
            new_letter -= 26

        new_letter = chr(new_letter + ord('a'))
        encrypted.append(new_letter)

    # make the list a string again with the join command
    return "".join(encrypted)

print ('encrypted message:')
print ('_')
print (keyword_encrypt)(shift_key, phrase)
```

Comment: Just write `print(keyword_encrypt(shift_key, phrase))`

Comment: thank you @StoryTeller. How stupid of me for not checking. ROFL :p

Answer (score 1):

The code are trying to call the result of the `print()` function:

```
result = print (keyword_encrypt)
result(shift_key, phrase)
```

That won't work, because `print()` always returns `None`.

You probably meant to call `keyword_encrypt()` function instead and print the return value of that call:

```
print(keyword_encrypt(shift_key, phrase))
```

The code is written a little funkily, with the parentheses and spaces, but if you actually ran it with Python 2 (as the first `#!` line of the file tries to do), the code as posted would actually work. That's because `print` is a statement in Python 2 and the parentheses around `keyword_encrypt` are effectively ignored.